# Alterar valor de uma variável com uma check box PHP

Tags: php

Quando clico na opção queria enviar por get, um valor. Tipo algo deste género

```
    <form action='_cal.php?change=1' method="get">
        <input type="checkbox" name="change" value="change">Alterar<br>
    </form>
```

e receber no PHP

```
$change=(isset($_GET['change']) ? $_GET['change'] : '0');
```

Consigo com um link, queria agora alterar por um checkbox.

Comment: Como o form está sendo enviado?

Comment: Por GET. Quero enviar para a mesma página.

Comment: Então é só mudar o `value="change"` para `value="1"`na linha do `input` e tirar o `?change=1` da linha do `form`.

Comment: Notar que essas perguntas de alterar variável não tem muito sentido, visto que, com a arquitetura padrão, não é possível alterar nada que é feito em PHP por meio de um HTML ou JS/Ajax. O que está acontecendo é o envio de novas informações. Quando um HTML ou JS está executando, o PHP que os gerou já foi processado e já acabou de "rodar". Sempre você estará chamando uma execução nova do PHP, seja ele o mesmo _script_ ou outro.

Comment: Tente por AJAX , fazendo uma requisição assincrona , de uma pesquisada sobre este assunto , sera de grande utilizade

Comment: Teria como você reescrever sua pergunta com mais detalhes e informando o que exatamente deseja fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Essencialmente o que procuras é submeter o formulário quando alguém clica na `checkbox` ao invés de usares links.

Para esse efeito, podes adicionar um atributo `onChange` ao elemento `checkbox` que vai executar JavaScript responsável por despoletar a submissão do formulário:

```
<form action='_cal.php' method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="change" value="1" onChange="this.form.submit()"> Alterar
</form>
```

Repara que também alterei o endereço do formulário pois ao submeter o mesmo via `GET`, vai ser adicionado ao URL uma *string* no formato [NVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute%E2%80%93value_pair) dos campos presentes no mesmo.

A tua `checkbox` chama-se `change` e com o valor `1`, em combinação com o URL `_cal.php` para onde o formulário vai submeter a informação, vais obter:

```
_cal.php?change=1
```

---

**Nota adicional:**

Para verificares a presença da varíavel de URL `change`, podes simplificar o teu código para:

```
$change = (int)isset($_GET['change']);
```

Para explicar, a função `isset()` devolve um booleano `TRUE` ou `FALSE`. Precedida por `(int)` vai passar o booleano para a sua representação numérica `1` ou `0`.

Ver demonstração no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/pbxewr).

Answer (score 0):

Segue aqui o código da página index.php que fiz para teste, utilizei apenas php, html e jquery:

```
<?php
    // Código php pra dar a resposta do ajax
    // Se o get for setado (se o checkbox for marcado)
   if (isset($_GET["change"])) { 
        // Imprime o get (no caso, retorna o valor pra nossa variável data
        echo $_GET["change"];

        // Dá o exit, 
        // pois aqui na minha máquina ele estava retornado o código fonte de toda
        // a página html
        exit();
   } 
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Teste get</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action='index.php' method="get" id="form">
            <input type="checkbox" name="change" value="1" id="change">Alterar<br>
        </form>

        <div id="resultado" style="margin: 20px auto; width: 300px"></div>

        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                // Evento JQuery que captura as mudanças do checkbox - pode ser substituído pelo click()
                $('#change').change(function() {

                    // Se o checkbox estiver :checked
                    if ( this.checked ) {

                        // Guarda o value do input numa variável
                        var chkData = $('#change').val();

                        // Inicia evento ajax, aqui é basicamente a resposta que você procura
                        $.ajax({
                            url: $('#form').attr("action") + "?" + $('#form').serialize(),  // Pega a URL no formato do get
                            type: 'GET',    // Define o tipo do submit
                            data: chkData,  // Aplica o valor do checkbox à variável data

                            // Caso o request termine em sucesso, mostra o resultado recebido na div#resultado
                            success: function(data) {
                                $("#resultado").html("Funcionou!!<br />" + data);
                            },
                            error: function(e) {
                                console.log(e.message);
                            }
                        }); 
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sei que a pergunta do autor não está tão clara, mas a sua resposta está menos ainda. Considere dar mais detalhes, como qual linguagem você está utilizando, que framework etc...